# Pause UI, while update data on postExecute in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm using sockets in my app. I created a class `SocketClient` with methods: `onConnect`, `onSendData`, `onReadData`. Method `onReadData` extends `AsyncTask`. It waits for a string message from the server inside `doInBackground` and then makes a new task to listen for the incoming message. Now I want to pause the UI in my MainActivity class while the message is loading and get it, but don't know how to do that. My Async Task looks like:

```
 public void ReadMyData() {
        mt = new ReadDataAsync();
        mt.execute();
    }


    class ReadDataAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           // a lot of work
                return message;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ReadMyData();
        }
    }
```

and MainActivity:

```
public SocketClient mySocketClient = new SocketClient();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                mySocketClient.onConnect();
                   //there I need wait message load and take it
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
                WorkWithMessage(message);}
```

Comment: I wouldn't "pause" the UI thread but you could use a progress bar/dialog to show a message to the user that things are happening by implementing `onPreExecute()` and/or `onProgressUpdate()`

Answer (score 0):

Create a progress DIALOG and start it when you know the message is loading, than take it off when the message is loaded.

You can create a progress DIALOG like this:

```
ProgressDialog pd = New ProgressDialog();
pd.setTitle(”title”);
pd.setMessage(”messgae”);
pd.setCancleable(false);
```

Than call

```
pd.show();
```

When you wish to load the message, and

```
pd.dismiss();
```

When you’r done.